# Websocketpp Cpp Keeps Giving Random Errors

Tags: c++, websocket

im trying to include websocketpp in my c++ project, I have everything included correctly like VC Directories etc & all that. And i just keep getting errors. It even gives me some errors in some of the windows header files. If anyone could help, that would be amazing. Thanks!

```
//how im including
#include "external/websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp"
#include "external/websocketpp/client.hpp"

using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;
typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;
```

One of the errors:
"redeclaration cannot add dllexport/dllimport to "setsockopt" (declared at line 829 of "C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winsock.h"

Thanks guys.

Comment: What are those errors?

Comment: Some of the errors are like a windows header i can't remember what its called but one of the windows headers is freaking out and giving me tons of errors.

Comment: That simply means you did not add those headers somehow. Read the installation manual again.

Comment: I have the correct headers, but the code inside of the headers are giving me errors when ever i include websocketpp

Comment: Heres actually one of the errors "redeclaration cannot add dllexport/dllimport to "setsockopt" (declared at line 829 of "C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winsock.h"

Comment: You might want to fix the subject line of your question, there doesn't seem to be anything random going on.